# After effects: How to change audio source using expressions (or other script way)?

Tags: audio, after-effects

I need to generate many videos that differs only by some Text objects and sound.
So I use command "aerender" and expressions that get source text from enviropment varibles.

I easially use expressions to change  Sorce Text. 
But I can't use it to change audio source. Option "Animation-> Add Expression" is inactive, when "Audio->Waveform" is selected on "Timeline" panel.

So, how to change audio source using expressions (or other script way)?

PS
Audio is added using "File -> Import". Shall I add audio using other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use extendscript to duplicate your original comp, exchange the audio layer and add them to the render queue.
Or you can use the render queues `RenderQueueItem status attribute` to execute the change on `onStatusChanged`. (Also in extendscript) This can execute a callback function where you could exchange your audio layer. This could be done in a recursive way.

Comment: Thanks. I understood how to change audio sourse from extended script. (it is something like this "app.project.item(16).replace(file)") 
But I can't figure out how to run my script, when aerender comand started.  I have a error "Unable to call "item" because of parameter 1. The range has no values."

Comment: I think you can't add something like a scritp callback onto a render started from the command line. If you are running from the command line i would suggest creating all those comps. If you are running it from an running instance of AE you can use these callback methods

Comment: Yes, I am running aerender from command line. What do you mean saying "creating all those comps"? Should I make as many compositions as different sounds? But I have about 500 thousands sounds :)

Comment: I don't think that you can trigger a script from the command line render. Is it 500 to 1000 or 500000? The second would be hard to create all at once. A solution could be. 1. Create one comp inside AE 2. Trigger the render via Extendscript (in the GUI not command line) 3. on Render ready via callback edit the comps audio layer 4 send the comp into the render queue again. 5 goto 3. … and so on

Comment: Is 500 000. I decided to use ffmpeg for adding audio. It is really easy.